# Default language when visiting websites

Tags: networking, language, website, international

I'm located in Italy and at home I have a LAN with several devices. All devices run different o.s. but they are in Italian or in English. My desktop and notebook computers are set in Italian, etc...

It happens sometimes that some websites propose me their *Polish* version. It doesn't happen all the time with even the same website, and it doesn't depend from which device I do the request (hence it's not device-related).

Ok, my wife comes from Poland and she might do some google searches from *her own smartphone* in Polish.

Is this enough to "track" me as Polish? I'm not talking on Internet websites only, the weirdest thing is that happens also with the [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/) webserver that runs on my own NAS inside my house!

Comment: Check in [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com) your public IP address. it will show a location. This location is extracted from a database of region-assigned IP ranges. Maybe your IP address is related to Poland  in that database.

Comment: Mine is static ip address and always point to Rome, Italy. Already checked this. Anyway it doesn't explain the behavior *inside* my LAN.

Comment: check your router, try to change DNS to google DNS for example, then clean Temp files on all devices, there is no other ways if your Public IP in italy,

Comment: Does your wife's smartphone connect to your LAN? If so, the website might be remembering the last language used from your (public) IP _on its end_ rather than by cookie.